# (com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText) Text Don't Adjust properly on API 28

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/material_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/material_input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_task_hint"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Before adding Margin** [image]

First Character is not visible Clearly.

**After Adding Margin start :**[image]

The text goes off the Boundary Of Text input Layout.

Comment: Can you use padding here from start and end .

Comment: @VrushiPatel   I have tried adding padding in multiple ways but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show me ? @user9717489

Answer (score 0):

**Use `android:maxLength="12"` in your `textInputEditText` :**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/material_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_task_hint"
            android:maxLength="12"
            />
```

For example 12 or any other number.